# Threading configuration for microservices written in java/jersey/grizzly

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, grizzly, microservices

I am designing a micro-services based system. Most of the services are deployed as standalone Jersey processes with an embedded Grizzly web server.

Assuming that many of those services will execute on the same machine, shall I change any threading configuration in Grizzly to prevent a situation of too many threads machine-wide?

What is the default threading model for Grizzly? Is there a limit for number of threads that a single web server can create?

Comment: What does the Grizzly documentation say about it?

Comment: I could not find any concrete answer, the most informative resource I found was https://grizzly.java.net/bestpractices.html.

Comment: Doesn't the first and last case explicitly target your question?

Comment: no, because I ask about *multiple* processes on the same machine. Shall I limit each of them or stay with the default settings?

Comment: Oh come on. If there are suggested limits for a single Grizzly instance, then obviously they would be halved for 2 instances, quartered for 4 instances etc. The amount of resources stays the same after all, unless you have a magical computer.

Comment: I don't think its that simple, because putting a hard limit on the number of threads for each service may be problematic if one service is busier than others. If all services were to run on the same thread pool, the balancing could be wiser.

Comment: If you want the services to share a thread pool, make them share an application server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you do with the incoming data.

If you need to process the data (cpu time > io time), then you need to match the number of physical cores to the number of data processing threads.

If most of the time is spent in IO (retrieving/storing the data) then you can start with cores * 2 and set the max to something that you must determine through testing the cpu usage and the throughput. I personally like the powers of 4 per core (4, 16, 64, 256). This will quickly narrow you down down onto the order of magnitude.

https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/coreconfig.html#/Thread_Pool_Configuration